# Are Pokemon in Pokemon Go similar to Pokemon in the original games?

Tags: pokemon-go, pokemon-series, version-differences

I was wondering if Pokemon in Pokemon GO have something in common with original Pokemons from the original games (Pokemon Blue/Red, FireRed/LeafGreen etc).

For example, moves and levels from original game can be found in Pokemon database's [Pokedex](http://pokemondb.net/pokedex/national). But do Pokemon in Pokemon GO have same/similar moves and levels as Pokemon in original games?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The moves and Pokemon are very similar to the original Blue, Red and Yellow games. The dynamics about how to evolve a Pokemon work different though.

They will most likely add more Pokemon and moves as time goes on to keep players engaged with the game. You can find a [list of all the Pokemon available](http://www.pokemon-go-wiki.com/Pokemon), which will show the moves for some Pokemon as well. I guess this data will get updated as players find out about the details of all the Pokemon available in the game.

Comment: A lot of the available moves were actually added in subsequent games, such as Steel Wing, Power Whip, and so on

Answer (score 2):

Well it has the original 150/151 Pokemon and their moves. So instead of something in common it's more like a re-imagining of the original pokemon games.

Comment: What is the missing 1 pokemon?

Comment: @Damek That would be Mew, we do not know if it's in the game.

Comment: I don't recall Dark or Ghost types being in the original games, nor do I remember seeing Steel Wing or Aerial Ace as moves for the bird families. I'd love to see an established source for what gen the moveset is based off- because it is *definitely* not first gen. My mistake- Ghost was in Gen1, but dark definitely wasn't, and I have a Raticate with a Dark bite ability

Comment: It could be the moves up to Gen 3 then. Since Aerial Ace was introduced there.

Comment: Venusaur can have Petal Blizzard as one of its powerful moves, and that's a gen 6 move

Comment: @Pyritie Ah, didn't know about that. So it looks like they've taken all of the moves from the later types. Hope they'll end up adding more Pokemon as well

Comment: @Riley At this year's E3 they said they plan on adding everything eventually.